# How to fix "No such file or directory: 'AppleStore.csv'"?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a csv file and I put it at D:\Subin\PYTHON\AppleStore.csv

Then I launch my Jupyter Notebook with the url: http://localhost:8888/notebooks/PYTHON/test.ipynb

I try to run this script:

```
open_file = open('AppleStore.csv')
```

Then I get the issue:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-7784a3a20685> in <module>
----> 1 open_file = open('AppleStore.csv')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'AppleStore.csv'
```

the `test.ipynb` is at same directory with `AppleStore.csv` But I dont understand why I got file not found issue.

Anyone have idea about this?

Comment: Use the full path, and see if you still get that error.

Comment: could you explain more @Aryerez? I have to use `open_file = open('D:\Subin\PYTHON\AppleStore.csv')` right?

Comment: If that's where it's suppose to be. But add `r` before the first " ' ".

Comment: type following command in the notebook `print("my path is ", os.getcwd())` and you will see why the file couldn't be found. The present working directly is very probably not what you thought it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running python from within Jupyter, your working directly is likely where Juptyer is installed. Within your notebook, use `print("my path is ", os.getcwd())` to check what your working directory is. ([credit to gelonida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123667/how-to-fix-no-such-file-or-directory-applestore-csv#comment104478780_59123667_))

Either use the full path to the file, or change your current working directory to the folder where the file is. `os.chdir(FOLDER PATH GOES HERE)`

For both of the code samples in this answer, you'll need to first `import os`.